# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError Error for defined functions

Tags: javascript, function, public

I am trying to write a public function that can be called within the object function and also outside the object function.
For example, here is a very simple greeting object with a public function hello that prints hello.

```
var greeting = function()
{

    this.hello = function(){ console.log("hello"); } 
    this._hello = function()
    {
        hello(); // first call, Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined
    }

    _hello(); // second call, Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined 

}

var g = new greeting();
g.hello(); // third call, Good
```

The hello function is obviously defined in the greeting function itself, but **Why** it is getting Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined from the first call and the second call, but not in the third call above.

Comment: `this.hello()` - problem solved.

Comment: What if this line this._hello = function() becomes function _hello()

Comment: Just to answer my own question, if _hello becomes private function, the first hello call will be this.hello();, the second one need to be _hello.call(this);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you use the `this` prefix to define a function, it can't be called with no prefix, like you're trying to do. Using `this` prefix makes it a property, which can only be called using the `this` prefix, or any other prefix that refers to the object instance. With no prefix, the function must be in either the local or a higher scope.

If you want to call it like property with the prefix and also without the prefix inside the object, you can do:

```
var greeting = function()
{
    function hello()
    {
        console.log("hello");
    }
    this.hello = hello;
    hello();
}

var g = new greeting();
g.hello();
```

This creates a local function `hello` that is not a property. It then creates a property `hello` which refers to the local function `hello`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to call the methods without the reference to the object (this)

Comment: I really do think questions under the JavaScript tag are getting more and more trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call hello with its object alias ('this.hello'). That is the only way to access that function.

Without trying to be rude, I think you need to do a lot more reading from some beginner JavaScript resources.